# Merge 2 json arrays based on their keys

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

How can I merge 2 json arrays based on the same keys and add a 3rd item from the input json `pog_id` in the output json file? I have tried with the code mentioned below that is creating 2 different arrays inside a key in json and not merging the values inside a same array.

**`mergedobject.json`**

```json
[
    {
        "name": "ALL_DMZ",
        "objectIds": [
            "29570",
            "29571"
        ],
        "orgid": "777777",
        "pog_id": "333333"
    },
    {
        "name": "ALL_DMZ",
        "objectIds": [
            "729548",
            "729549",
            "295568"
            
        ],
        "orgid": "777777",
        "pog_id": "333333"
    }
    
]
```

**`Playbook`**

```yaml
- set_fact:
        output: "{{ output|d([]) + [{'orgid': item.0,
                                     'objectIds': item.1|
                                                  map(attribute='objectIds')|
                                                  list}] }}"
      loop: "{{ mergedobject|groupby('name') }}"
```

**Current Output**

```json
[
    {
        "name": "ALL_DMZ",
        "objectIds": [
        [   "29570",
            "29571"
        ],
        [
            "729548",
            "729549",
            "295568"  
        ]
      ]
        "orgid": "777777"
    }
    
]
```

**Expected Output**

```json
[
    {
        "name": "ALL_DMZ",
        "objectIds": [
            "29570",
            "29571",
            "729548",
            "729549",
            "295568"  
      ]
        "orgid": "777777",
        "pog_id": "333333"
    }
    
]
```

Comment: `item.1 | map(attribute='objectIds') | list | flatten`, since you've got a list of lists

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε
Thank you so much for the solution. Could you please let me know how can i add a 3rd variable in the same output JSON as pog_id(from mergedobject.json). Kindly post this as answer, so that i can accept your solution.

Comment: I cannot answer that question. How should multiple value be merged? What if they are all similar? What if they are not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the data

```yaml
  mergedobject:
    - name: ALL_DMZ
      objectIds: ['29570', '29571']
      orgid: '777777'
      pog_id: '333333'
    - name: ALL_DMZ
      objectIds: ['729548', '729549', '295568']
      orgid: '777777'
      pog_id: '333333'
```

---

[*combine*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) the items in the list. Append the lists in attributes

```yaml
  output: "{{ mergedobject|combine(list_merge='append') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  output:
    name: ALL_DMZ
    objectIds: ['29570', '29571', '729548', '729549', '295568']
    orgid: '777777'
    pog_id: '333333'
```

You can put the result into a list

```yaml
  output: "[{{ mergedobject|combine(list_merge='append') }}]"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  output:
    - name: ALL_DMZ
      objectIds: ['29570', '29571', '729548', '729549', '295568']
      orgid: '777777'
      pog_id: '333333'
```